# How to write console output to a user named file

Tags: java, console, output

My issue is simple. And I am sure the solution is simple too. But my attempts have failed. I looked on every question on here that relates to this but it does not contain the solution I am looking for. I am using a ReadGameFile() method and a WriteToGameFile() method that is in my class VideoGameManager. I have a class that contains a method that outputs data in the following way : 
this class is called VideoGameManager
which has a method that is called public void printSearchCriteria(String nameInput,String consoleInput);

name (tab space) platform

name "         " platform

name "         " platform

....etc.

then in a main class I have a new instance of VideoGameManaer

VideoGameManager vG = new VideoGameManager();

I then call the method that outputs the data with the following parameters

in which the user inputs

nameInput = keyboard.next();

consoleInput = keyboard.next();

vG.printSearchCriteria(String nameInput, String consoleInput);

This results in the data being printed in the way which was stated above. 
I now need to find a way to take that output. and store it in new file in which the user will name.

System.out.println("Enter the file name to print out.");

String fileNamePrintToFile = keyboard.next();

//Some way that takes the data from the output of printSearchCriteria and stores it in a new file from the user input -fileNamePrintToFile.

VideoGameManager File

```
public class VideoGameManager {
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
//array list
private ArrayList<VideoGame> games; 
//tab
private static final String delim = "\t";

//constructor
public VideoGameManager(){
    games = new ArrayList<VideoGame>();
}


public void ReadGameFile(String fileName)
{
    //This reconstructs a new instance of the VideGame array list.
    //This is done to clear the array list
    games = new ArrayList<VideoGame>();
    try
    {
        //Create a new file Scanner
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        //Reads each line in the file one-by-one
        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            //Stores the next line of code
            String nextLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
            //That line is then split using the delimiter (\t)
            String[] splitStrings = nextLine.split(delim);
            //If the newly created array is not 2 items in length then
            //that line is not correctly formatted and should be ignored.
            if(splitStrings.length != 2)
                continue;
            String gameName = splitStrings[0];//The first element is the game name
            String console = splitStrings[1];//Next is the console
            VideoGame newVideoGame = new VideoGame(gameName,console); 
            games.add(newVideoGame);//Added to the array list
        }
        fileScanner.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(" File does not exist ");
    }

}
public void WriteToGameFile(String fileName, boolean append)
{
    if(games == null)//if the file name is null then return
        return;
    try
    {
        //Creates the new instance of a print writer
        PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName,append));
        for(VideoGame aVideoGame : games)
        {
            //Prints to the file
            fileWriter.println(aVideoGame.getName()+delim+
                                aVideoGame.getConsole());
        }
        fileWriter.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
//returns an array list of video games based on a search criterion (name and console)
public void PrintSearchCriteria(String nameInput, String consoleInput)
{

    for(VideoGame aVideoGame : games)
    {
        if(aVideoGame.getName().contains(nameInput) == true && aVideoGame.getConsole().contains(consoleInput) == true)
        {
            VideoGame newVideoGame = new VideoGame(aVideoGame.getName(),aVideoGame.getConsole()); 
            System.out.println(newVideoGame.getName()+delim+newVideoGame.getConsole());

        }
        else if(aVideoGame.getName().contains(nameInput) == true && consoleInput.equalsIgnoreCase("*"))
        {
            VideoGame newVideoGame = new VideoGame(aVideoGame.getName(),aVideoGame.getConsole()); 
            System.out.println(newVideoGame.getName()+delim+newVideoGame.getConsole());

        }
        else if(nameInput.equalsIgnoreCase("*") && aVideoGame.getConsole().contains(consoleInput) == true)
        {
            VideoGame newVideoGame = new VideoGame(aVideoGame.getName(),aVideoGame.getConsole()); 
            System.out.println(newVideoGame.getName()+delim+newVideoGame.getConsole());

        }

    }
}

public void PrintCurrentResults(String fileName)
{
    for(VideoGame aVideoGame : games)
    {
        System.out.println(aVideoGame.getName()+delim+
                                aVideoGame.getConsole());
    }
}
```

}

Main Class

```
public class VideoGameFrontEnd {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create and connect scanner object to keyboard
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    VideoGameManager vG = new VideoGameManager();
    System.out.println("Welcome to the video game database!");
    boolean quit = false;
    try{
    while(quit == false)
    {



    System.out.println("Enter 1 to load the video game database");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 to search the database");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 to print current results");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 to print current results to file");
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to quit");
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();

    switch(input){
    case 0: input = 0;
        System.out.println("Good Bye");
        quit = true;
        break; 

    case 1: input = 1;
        System.out.println("Enter the file Name");
        String fileName = keyboard.next();
        vG.ReadGameFile(fileName);
        break;
    case 2: input = 2;
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the game or '*' for all names");
        String nameInput = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the console or '*' for all consoles");
        String consoleInput = keyboard.next();
        vG.PrintSearchCriteria(nameInput,consoleInput);

        break;
    case 3: input = 3; 
        //print current results
        break;
    case 4: input = 4;

        System.out.println("Enter the file name to print out.");
        String fileNamePrintToFile = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Append to file ? True or False");
        String appendToFile = keyboard.next();
        if(appendToFile.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            vG.WriteToGameFile(fileNamePrintToFile, true);
        }
        else if(appendToFile.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
        {
            vG.WriteToGameFile(fileNamePrintToFile, false);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Response, auto shutdown");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    default: 
        break;

        }

    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("error");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

}

Comment: I would suggest you to use a logging framework. log4j is one such, have a look at it. http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest logging framework like log4j,slf4j and so on. Or java standard logging utils.

If you want to know, how to save all the outputs send by System.out.print or println, here is one of the way, how you can achieve.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("mylog.log");
        System.setOut(ps);
        System.out.println(String.format("%s: %s", new Date(),"Application Started"));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s: %s", new Date(),"Application Terminated"));
    }
```

And the output will be some thing like this,
[image]